# Testlink backup file size issue

Tags: testlink

We are using Testlink and everything is working fine. We also schedule automatic backup for testing and it generates backup everyday at define time. From few weeks i observed that the file size generated for backup is not getting increase more that 34MB. Even some time size automatically get reduced from previous backup without deleting anything in the project. Can anybody help to find the reason or anyone else have observed same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is the backup taking the attachments and screenshots?Maybe it can be the reason...

Can you please provide more information related to the scheduled automatic backup?

Regards, David.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply. There is no attachment and no screenshot. We just upload test cases in projects and execute it.

Comment: We are generating SQL backup file using "mysqldump" command. We are copying this .sql file using "cp" command to another PC. For schedule backup we are using "crontab" command.

Answer (score 0):

give a look to audit tables (transaction & events) may be you are getting lot of warning (useless to back) warning messages